# Get sha1 message digest from plaintext+private key in delphi

Tags: delphi, sha1, private-key, message-digest

I want to create a Sha1 message digest, and it should use my private key as input along with the plain text.

Everything I have found so far either dont use a private key or just take a lot of certificates as input.

Comment: By `privatekey` you mean `salt`?

Comment: Wish you'd listed which packages you've tried. That would really help to give a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use DCPCrypt for my crypto needs.
http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/dcpcrypt

It's opensource and works really well.
After installing the package, use TDCP_sha1 and drop that on a form.
Then look up how to use the component in the help files in the `DOC` directory in the zip file.

Comment: Does it really do anything else than plain hashing? I need to included my private key as input to the hash.

Comment: Yes it does everything and the kitchen sink. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at TurboPower [LockBox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tplockbox/)

Comment: LockBox 2 or 3? I did not find 2. I installed 3 but it failed already when I tried to run the demo program that was not found.